# Save and open the content of a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm working on a text editor as part of a school project and i'm having a small issue with my save and open code.

Here are my buttons:

```
<button id="gu" onclick="save()">Save</button>
<button id="ab" onclick="open()">Open</button>
```

Here's my textarea:

```
<textarea name="comment" rows=30 cols=101 id="texto"></textarea>
```

And here's my javascript functions:

```
function save(){
    gu = document.getElementById("texto");
    localStorage.setItem("texto",gu);
    console.log(texto+"="+gu);
}

function open(){
    console.log("Abierto")
    document.getElementById('texto').innerHTML=gu;
}
```

My goal is that if write something and then press the "save" button, the content inside my `textarea` is saved, and if i press the "open" button it shows what i wrote on the `textarea`.

Any idea on how to fix my code?

Sorry if my english is bad.

Comment: Use code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/cinerobert/qwgv18r5/

```
function save()
{
    localStorage.setItem("someitem", document.getElementById("texto").value);
    document.getElementById("texto").value = "";
    console.log(texto + "=" + gu);
}

function retrieve(){
        console.log("Abierto")
        document.getElementById("texto").value = localStorage.getItem("someitem");
}
```

You can't use open() as a function name because it's already a built-in function in javascript, so I changed it to retrieve(). See here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Is there some reason you're required to use setItem()? Using a variable (gu) *and* setItem is redundant. It would work either way.

Also to get and set the text inside a text area I you need to use value().

I also changed the save() function so that it clears the textbox, so that you can see something happen when you click retrieve().

Answer (score 0):

Below are the things need to be done

```
 function save()
{
    gu = document.getElementById("texto");
    localStorage.setItem("texto",gu.innerText);  //here you were saving the dom object not the text inside
    console.log(texto+"="+gu.innerHTML);

}

function open()
{

console.log("Abierto")
document.getElementById('texto').innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("texto"); //here you need to get the text from your local storage
```

}

Comment: Textareas do not have `innerText` or `innerHTML`.  By the way, `innerText` is a non-standard property anyway.